# Using multiple models on user creation

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm looking to use an Account model I created to handle financial data about a user. How do I ensure django-allauth will create this model when registering users and will link through keys both the new user and the Account model?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom pipeline. First modify `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` in django `settings` file like this:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
'yourapp.pipeline.add_account'
)
```

Then in `yourapp` create `pipeline` module or you can use already existing model and inside this model create function `add_account` with following code:

```
def add_account(backend, details, response, user=None, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if is_new:
        Account.objects.create(user=user)
```

You can find more details [here](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html) and [here](https://7webpages.com/blog/additional-data-receipt-from-social-networks-by-dj/).

UPDATE

Pipelines is just functions wich will be called by django-allauth during autentication process. So you can add some custom function to this procedure.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how pipelines work, can you provide more details please?

Comment: How come you put user=user for the Account creation? Don't I only need to use a pk?

Comment: Plus, why are there so many pipelines specified from social.pipeline

Comment: @AlexCreamer since user argument is an object it is more simple to pass objects to queryset. But you can use id as well. I just copied pipelines from project. You can remove some of them.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion and I was unable to get def add_account called after user registration